# Error App Engine -

Tags: java, google-app-engine

when I deploy my application, no error appears, however when I access my application, the following error appears:

Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

```
Erro Log on Google App Engine Admin:
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jsp/PessoaApplication_jsp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-6a9f678c146455a7(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:795)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Follow my homepage:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.User" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.bruno.bariotti.Pessoa" %>
<%@ page import="com.bruno.bariotti.PessoaDao" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Pessoas</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<%
PessoaDao dao = PessoaDao.INSTANCE;
List<Pessoa> pessoas;
pessoas = dao.listPessoas();
%>

Numero total de pessoas: <% pessoas.size(); %> Pessoas.

<table>
<tr>
<th>Nome</th>
<th>Idade</th>
<%for (Pessoa p : pessoas) {%>
<tr>
<td>
<%p.getNome(); %>
</td>
<td>
<%p.getIdade();  %>
</td>
</tr>
<% } %>
</table>

<hr />

<div class="main">
<div class="headline">Nova Pessoa</div>

<form action="/new" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<table>

<tr>
<td><lable for="nome">Nome</lable></td>
<td><input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" size="200"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><lable for="idade">Idade</lable></td>
<td><input type="text" name="idade" id="idade" size="3"/></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to look an the appengine console log for the stacktrace/error. Without that its unlikely anyone can help.

Comment: Tim, tks!

I edited the post above with the error log

Comment: Have you read the stack trace ?  The first line is pretty much telling you what is going on . - `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jsp/PessoaApplication_jsp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

Comment: See this google group thread  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine/Unsupported$20major.minor$20version$2052.0/google-appengine/T6Y1URjb9pI/Zc5ZaCl5st4J   I think you are not using JDK 7 but trying to compile with JDK 8, which I gather is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens when you use JDK 1.8 and deploy your application, say, using maven e.g. `mvn appengine:update`.

During the update process Google AppEngine maven plugin compiles JSP files (as on the image below) using JDK 1.8. Generated class files gets version number 52.0 which are not currently supported by Google AppEngine (hence your error: *Unsupported major.minor version 52.0*).

[image: JSP compilation]

Workaround is quite simple: set `JAVA_HOME` variable to point to your JDK 1.7

Example in Windows:

```
set JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05
```

After that you have to run `mvn appengine:update` again, which will fix the problem.

**JDK 1.7** is required by Google actually. You can find out more on [Using Apache Maven: Requirements](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#requirements).